# Vue 3 - cannot name ref same as prop - why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

If I define a property with the name 'foobar' and then try to create a ref with the name 'foobar', Vue complains that 'foobar' is undefined when I try to access that ref. This only happens when *building* the vue app e.g. npm run build, but not when serving it e.g. npm run dev. I'm not sure if it happens with Vue 2.

I can fix the issue simply by naming them different things but I am curious as to why this happens as there's nothing in the docs about it?

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
    foobar: {
        type: String
    }
})
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div ref="foobar">
        {{ foobar }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // error!
        const el = this.$refs.foobar;
    }
}
</script>
```

No error:

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
    foobar: {
        type: String
    }
})
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div ref="foobar2">
        {{ foobar }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // no error!
        const el = this.$refs.foobar2;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 script

Comment: it is perfectly fine to have as many script tags as one wants/needs.

Comment: Well.. seeing it for the first time somebody doing it like this

Comment: In Vue 3, you can refer to a Ref in the setup script by declaring a variable with the same name as the Ref. Ex: `const foobar = ref(null)`. It might be the reason for your problem